# Does the screensaver process halt when the screen is put to sleep?

Tags: power-management, screensaver

I've got some CPU/GPU intensive screen savers that I like to use. However, I don't want to spend the CPU/GPU cycles (read: electricity) on the screen saver process if the monitor is asleep or shut off.

Note that the machine in question is running all the time as it is acting as a home server. I have the screen set to sleep after 15 minutes but also power off the monitor when I have no plans on using the machine physically for an extended period of time.

Does OSX / macOS suspend or otherwise stop processing of a screen saver when the screen is sleeping or otherwise shut off?

Comment: Are you saying that your screen is asleep/off but your Mac is not asleep?

Comment: @Monomeeth the mac stays on most of the time and acts as a home server. So in other words, the screen can go to sleep or be powered off while the machine is running.